# I'm having an issue, while uploading an update to my app

Tags: android

**The app cannot declare different versions of Google Play services depending on the device configuration. The following versions were found: [0, 12451000]**

[Please find an attchament](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIjOZ.png)

this is issue I'm having. Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by changed `com.android.application` and  `com.android.library`  version from 7.3.0-alpha 07 to 7.1.2, worked without any problem

Comment: After changed gradle from 7.3.0 alpha07 to 7.1.2 the play store issue resolved. but having different issue while app runnin.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "app.bharatkrushiseva.com.Activity.SplashScreenActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file  "/data/data/app.bharatkrushiseva.com/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes10.dex"